# Is it possible to pass query result to functions or classes in Java with a DB

Tags: java, ms-access

I have an authorization window, where you have to input login and password, logins and password are stored in a MS Access Database like this:

```
 ID      login      password      ID_in_another_table
----    -------    ----------    ---------------------
  1      admin      admin
  2      user1      user1                           1
  3      user2      user2                           2
```

For authorization I'm using

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name
```

For administrator I have his own menu, but for user I must open data which has the same ID as **ID_in_another_table**, can I somehow pass that **ID_in_another_table** to a function or a class to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
SELECT ID_in_another_table
FROM Table_name
WHERE login = :login
AND password = :password
```

You would only get a result if the name and password match, and for the admin user you would get a single row returned but with a null value.  No result would mean the username or password were wrong.

Comment: I think you didn't understan what I mean, at login window user have to input hist login and password, but data which he can only see, will be with the ID_in_another_table.

Comment: I'm using:


ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Lietotaji WHERE Lietv=? AND Parole=?");

, but can I somehow pass the ID_in_another_table with this query to another class or function?